# Testing multiple boolean values in a single IF statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, boolean

I a newbie C++ programmer trying to test aruments/parameters passed to a program.

Multiple arguments can be passed to the program, however I want to test that if certain arguments are passed then other arguments become invalid.

e.g. PGM accepts arg(1) arg(2) arg(3) arg(4) arg(5) etc...

if arg(1) and arg(2) are supplied then arg(3), arg(4) and arg(5) etc... are invalid and the program should terminate with an error message if they are also supplied along with arg(1) and arg(2).

I've thought that using boolean IF tests would be a good way to check if certain values are true/false.

I searched on stackoverflow but not found an answer that encompasses exactly what i'm trying to do. If someone can point me in the right direction or suggest a far more efficient way of doing this I would be very grateful.

My code currently looks like this:

```cpp
bool opt1 = false; 
bool opt2 = false;
bool opt3 = false;
bool opt4 = false;
bool opt5 = false;

  for(int i=1; i<argc; i++)   {
        char *str  = argv[i];
        if      (strcmp (str, "-opt1:")==0) {opt1 = true;}
        else if (strcmp (str, "-opt2:")==0) {opt2 = true;}
        else if (strcmp (str, "-opt3:")==0) {opt3 = true;}
        else if (strcmp (str, "-opt4:")==0) {opt4 = true;}
        else if (strcmp (str, "-opt5:")==0) {opt5 = true;}        
     }

if((opt1) && (opt2) && (~(opt3)) && (~(opt4)) && (~(opt5)) {

      ** DO SOMETHING **

   } else {

       ** DISPLAY ERROR MESSAGE AND USAGE TEXT **

   }
```

Comment: Switch from bitwise not to the logical not (`!opt3 && !opt4`), but otherwise I don't see an issue with this.  Are you running into problems with this approach?

Comment: Do not confuse with too many parantheses and use `!` instead of `~`: `if (opt1 && opt2 && !opt3 && !opt4 && !opt5)`

Comment: Maybe the *error case* corresponds to `opt1 && opt2 && (opt3 || opt4 || opt5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good solution would be using operands `!` and `&&`
`!` denotes "not" (or in such case "not true") while `&&` combines two different logical comparisons (in such case, "logic test 1" and "logic test 2")


Here's an example to do it:

```
if((opt1 && opt2)&&(!(opt3||opt4||opt5))){
   /*
     Do something if opt1 and opt2 are true and others are false
   */
}
```

This is practically the same as @Fareanor's solution above (first solution)

Comment: This is not the same because you don't handle the case where opt1, opt2 and opt3 are valid, so you cannot test everything in a single if.

Comment: @Fareanor I just compounded your first IF with its sub-IF with ~~~&&~~~ It's just practically your code, I just did some edits.

Comment: @SilverousBlack No you don't understand. It is not the same, because you don't handle the case where `(opt1 && opt2)` is false and so `opt3`, `opt4` and `op5` become valid. That is the reason because you can't put everything in a single chain of `&&`

Comment: Writing `if(A && B){}` is equal to `if(A){if(B){}}` only if there is no `else` statements.

Comment: ahhh I see what you mean @Fareanor. I was implying that I only compounded `if(opt1&&opt2)` and its sub-path `if(!(opt3||opt4||opt5)`

Answer (score 1):

A possible fix could be (if I have well understood your problem):

```
if(opt1 && opt2) // opt3, opt4 and opt5 are invalid
{
    if(!(opt3 || opt4 || opt5))
    {
        // Do something
    }
    else
    {
        // Display error message because at least opt3 or opt4 or opt5 is provided and not requested
    }
}
else // opt3, opt4 and opt5 are valid
{
    // Do something
}
```

But I think it could be better to just ignore the obsolete parameters instead of display an error while you can still run your process with only `opt1` and `opt2`. Which could lead us to the simpler code:

```
if(opt1 && opt2)
{
    // Do something without using opt3, opt4 and opt5
}
else
{
    // Do something taking into account opt3, opt4 and opt5
}
```

I hope it is what you was looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the help.